# IE 8 Error on creating UI widgets on cloned elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, datetimepicker

I am trying to clone a `<tr>` element on a button click. I then need to instantiate a UI Widget on an input within the new `<tr>`. It works fine on **FireFox**, **Chrome** and **IE7** but not on *IE8*.

Here is my HTML :

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="day-name">
        <span class="label label-info">Date</span>
    </td>
    <td class="log-time">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label id="time-label"></label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="time[]" class="xlarge" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button title="Add" class="btn btn-primary add-time" type="button">
            <i class="icon-white icon-plus"></i>
        </button>
    </td>  
</tr>
</table>
```

and here is my javascript code :

```
    $('td.log-time input').timepicker({
        onOpen: function(){
            $(this).val('00:00');
        },
        stepMinute: 15,
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
        hourMax: 8
    });

    $('.add-time').click(function() {

        var cloned = $(this).parents('tr').eq(0).clone().addClass('cloned');
        $('td.date span', cloned).remove()
        $('button.add-time', cloned).remove();

        cloned.insertAfter($('tr').last());

        $('td.log-time input', cloned)
            .removeClass('hasDatepicker')
            .timepicker({ //The error occur here
                onOpen: function(){
                    $(this).val('00:00');
                },
                stepMinute: 15,
                timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
                hourMax: 8
            });

    });
```

As I said, it works fine on FireFox, Chrome and IE7 but not on IE8. I get this error instead : `This object does not support this property or method` (on the line in which I create new instance of timepicker widget).

It is not a problem of the `timepicker` plugin. I tried with the `jQuery UI spinner` widget also and had the same behaviour / error.

[UPDATE] 
**I'm using jQuery 1.8.1 and jQuery UI 1.9.1**

[UPDATE 2]  due to user asking about timePicker plugin used (even I think it is not matter of timepicker plugin)

The timepicker plugin used is this one : http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js

Comment: What versions of jquery and jquery-ui are you using?

Comment: jQuery 1.8.1
jQuery UI 1.9.1

Comment: Which timepicker plugin are you using?

Comment: @Fresh, Sorry but it's not matter of timePicker. It's not working even with jQuery UI Spinner

Comment: Its worth letting people know exactly what timepicker you are using so that they can recreate your problem.

Comment: @Fresh, Question updated with plugin used. Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Hey! Short answer, hope it works: try passing "true" as parameter when using the clone method, I mean `.clone(true)` http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: Tested with IE8 and working fine here, are you directly linking to timepicker URL lib? The site has a direct link blocker to stop people direct linking to it which sounds like your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used your exact code with the same library versions and IE8 worked fine.

However, I did notice another issue which might be causing you problems.

The issue you have is that once the date picker input is clicked, there are two `table` elements on the page. One in your initial HTML and another, dynamically inserted one inside an element with the id `ui-datepicker-div`. This additional table is used to show the date picker's calendar layout but since you're not using it it's hidden.

Once you've clicked a date picker input any subsequent clicks on the `.add-time` button will append the cloned `tr` to last `tr` element in the second, hidden table. The reason is that your selector (`$('tr').last()`) isn't specific enough.

Adding a class to the original table like this `<table class="my-table">` then changing the `insertAfter` line to: `cloned.insertAfter($('table.my-table tr').last());` fixes this and definitely works in IE8 without any problems.